# How to properly resize a Bootstrap panel with jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently struggling with resizing panels in Twitter Bootstrap with the jQuery UI `resizable`. Horizontal resize works fine (sometimes the resize bars get moved though), but vertical resize acts weird. Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Nyze/

I've tried setting height to 100% in both the `.panel` and the `.panel-body` but that just causes the `.panel-body` to overflow the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, I ended up just tacking a `resizable` that was on the `e` side to the `.panel` and then tacking a `resizable` that was on the `s` side to the `.panel-body` and making the `.panel-body` have a `height: 100%`. It works well enough.